# Windows 10 Weather and Settings apps launching of their own accord

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

On a machine running Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (1607, 14965.1001), the Weather app and the Settings app launch of their own accord, in the background rather than the foreground. I notice them, close them and return to work. Some time later they are running again. I have not yet been able to work out the interval as I don't notice when they start up.

I have checked the Task Scheduler and it seems to show nothing that would cause this. I have no third-party software set up to do this (and running these apps on a schedule is not the sort of thing one would usually do) nor can I find any keyboard shortcuts that might be responsible.

What on earth could be causing these two apps to start like this? There are plenty of questions about apps refusing to start, this is the reverse of that.

EDIT: And now the Films & TV app as well.

Comment: If you are on build 14965 then you are not running 1607, you are using an Insider Preview build, its entirely possible you have simply discovered a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are known issues with current preview builds, the workaround is make these apps not open full screen.  Click the minimize box at the top right of the app screen and make it open in slightly smaller size, this should solve your problem.

Comment: I made this change and left it a few days and, somewhat to my surprise, it seems to have worked. No more apps popping up!